# Saved value of let variable in curried function

Tags: javascript, currying

I have a question about currying function which is returning the value from if statement, any time it has been called after first call.

I know that this is a currying function but don't understand, how the value has been saved in the let variable for the next consecutive calls? This doesn't make any sense for me.

I also don't understand the anonymous function passed as a first argument and another anonymous function used in the body.

Why the function call is happening with one brackets like this `test()`, instead `test()()`?

Can somebody explain this complicated peace of code?

```
const test = (() => {// <--- why is it passed as an argument?
  let variable = null; // <--- how on second call let variable is not empty and has the value in it???

  return () => {
    // <--- what is the role of this return empty function?
    if (variable) {
      console.log("returning in the if statement");
      return variable;
    }

    variable = "parrot";

    console.log("returning at the bottom");
    return variable;
  };
})(); // <--- is this still a currying function?

test();
test();
test();
```

Output:

```
returning at the bottom
returning in the if statement
returning in the if statement
```

Comment: There's no currying there. That's an immediately-invoked function expression that declares a `let` variable that's persistent over all calls of `test`, but not visible outside. It's nearly equivalent to `let variable = null; const test = () => { if (variable) { ...` except that there's no way to access `variable` outside.

Comment: ahh ok got it, thank you a lot for clarification.
could you please share your opinion what is the benefits of using the code above?
Because after your explanation I think that it is overcomplicated for no reason.

Comment: It can make it clearer that there's *absolutely no way* for the `variable` to be accessed or modified outside, which is potentially useful though arguably overly defensive sometimes - but there are usually better ways to accomplish that with ES modules

Comment: Can memoization be an alternative?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by an alternative - the code in the question *is* effectively memoization